# Adobe Director: on mousehover image resizes too small

Tags: adobe, shockwave, lingo, adobe-director

After setting a mouseover to an image of a door opening (so when you mouse over it appears to open), it changes to the other image however it SHRINKS the next sprite/image that it is meant to. 
I've tried adjusting the width, scaling the sprite, and even changing the actual file size of the image but none of it works.

It's for a school project due very soon so help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseover-handler your can try something like this:

1. Exchange the image for the sprite
2. updateStage -- that will redraw all elements
3. set the width and height of the sprite to the width and height of the image member for the second image

Hope that helps.